# Value getting removed from hashmap automatically

Tags: java, android

I add few key-value pairs to a hashmap.

After I add key-value pair, when I print the size of hashmap, I get the size as 1. When I print the value at another place(after adding value to key-hashmap), I get the size of hashmap as zero. I do not remove the value added to this hashmap from this class or any other external classes. Then , how the hashmap size becomes zero? Can someone please explain?

Any help is appreciated.

Code here:

```
private HashMap <Context,BLEEventListeners> mHashMapCallbacks = new HashMap<Context,BLEEventListeners>();
public void startTimeServer(BLEEventListeners eventListener,Context context) {
    mHashMapCallbacks.put(context, eventListener);
    Log.d(TAG,"****Inside startTimeServer,mHashMapCallbacks size: " +mHashMapCallbacks.size());// I get 1 as size
    Intent cmn_intent = new Intent(IServerCommon.class.getName());
    Intent time_intent = new Intent(ITimeServer.class.getName());
    mContext.bindService(time_intent, time_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.bindService(cmn_intent, cmn_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private ICommonResultCallback callback = new ICommonResultCallback.Stub() {
    public void receiveMessage(Bundle value) throws RemoteException {
        Log.d(TAG,"****Inside connected,mHashMapCallbacks size: "   +mHashMapCallbacks.size());// I get 0 as size
 }
        }
```

Comment: Your `mHashMapCallbacks` field is not static. Are you confident the same *instance* of your class is printing the zero message?

Comment: is `startTimeServer()`  invoked before `receiveMessage()` ??

Comment: ICommonResultCallback.Stub - is this a static inner class??? If so, then it can't access outer class variable.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICommonResultCallback() looks like a callback function. If it is, then hashmap will be initialized again when this function is called. This is because a new Instance of you class is created for call back also.

You can verify this by using making hashmap "static". It should then retain the value.

Answer (score 1):

Common Java Basics

```
private HashMap <Context,BLEEventListeners> mHashMapCallbacks = new HashMap<Context,BLEEventListeners>();
```

Here Context is your key which has to be unique every time otherwise a single hashmap doesn't contain your data, if you have use of only listener why don't you use List or ArrayList,

and still you have to do something with context do something like this

```
    private ArrayList<HashMap> tempArray = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    public void startTimeServer(BLEEventListeners eventListener,Context context) {
        HashMap <Context,BLEEventListeners> mHashMapCallbacks = new HashMap<Context,BLEEventListeners>();
        tempArray.add(mHashMapCallbacks);
        Log.d(TAG,"****Inside startTimeServer,mHashMapCallbacks size: " +mHashMapCallbacks.size());// I get 1 as size
        Intent cmn_intent = new Intent(IServerCommon.class.getName());
        Intent time_intent = new Intent(ITimeServer.class.getName());
        mContext.bindService(time_intent, time_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mContext.bindService(cmn_intent, cmn_connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ICommonResultCallback callback = new ICommonResultCallback.Stub() {
        public void receiveMessage(Bundle value) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG,"****Inside connected,Array size: "   +tempArray.size());// I get 0 as size
     }
            }
```